# How to reduce space between title and subtitle in JIDE BannerPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jide

How to reduce space between title and subtitle in JIDE `BannerPanel`?

Comment: [`BannerPanel.setSubTitleIndent(int)`](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/dialog/BannerPanel.html#setSubTitleIndent(int))?

Comment: No, it won't work..

Comment: No, it's not working. basically my requirement is to reduced the gap between title icon and subtitle(I'm not using title). there is some pre fixed gap between title and sub title, I already tried BannerPanel.setSubTitleIndent(int) but it's not resolving my problem.

Comment: *"I already tried .."* What you've already tried should be part of the explanation above, not dribbled out in comments.